# Trouble retrieving JSON on Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, httpconnection

I am trying to download weather data from OpenWeatherMap api. There are lots of tutorials for this and it seems really simple in practise, but I cannot get it working!

If I got to the url [Click Here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=rome)

You can see the JSON is formed..

Using my code:

```
public class RemoteFetch {

private static String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";




   public static JSONObject getJSON(String city) {

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(BASE_URL + city)).openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();

            // Let's read the response
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line + "\r\n");

            is.close();
            con.disconnect();
            String json = buffer.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", "value is " + json.toString());
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.e("JSON", "Value of request is " + data.getInt("cod"));


            // This value will be 404 if the request was not
            // successful
            if (data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
                return null;
            }

            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
            try {
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I don't receive anything, line is always null.

Comment: Is there any Exception thrown?

Comment: No need to as `\r\n` when reading JSON string from Stream just use `buffer.append(line );`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to learn how to fetch the JSON with an http connection yourself, but if not it could be easier for you to use a library like volley: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json

Answer (score 0):

Try this method get get response from server.

```
private static String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";


public String getInternetData(String city) throws Exception {


        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),
                    3000);

            URI website = new URL(BASE_URL + city)
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            //String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("GetMethodEx", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you must add the android.permission.INTERNET permission to your app's manifest

Answer (score 0):

[setDoOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#doInput) is used only when you want to post data to the server.While you mention the method as get.This chnages it to post.Please check the definitions and usecases  of setDoOuput() and setDoInput() and use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this will help you,

Create a class with getters and setters method for example

```
class A
{
int b;
void setb(int x){this.b = x;}
int getb(){return this.b}
}
```

than you can create json from the object of this class:

```
new Gson().toJson(a)
```

Or object from json:

```
a = new Gson().fromJson(data, A.class);
```